# Display content in a UWP app - XAML Control

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

[image]

I am trying to display the content of a UWP app exactly the same way the content is displayed in the Store app (see above).
I used a `ListView`, but the `Items` appear right of the `Header`, instead of appearing straight below it, as you can see on the following screenshot:

[image]

This is my XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:Items x:Key="Item"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="myListViewDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0" Width="200">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Path=ItemImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=ItemName}" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myListViewDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Item}">
        <ListView.Header>
            <TextBlock Margin="20,10,0,10" Text="Group of items" FontSize="22" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: You should post what have you tried so far. From what I know there's no exact control that can display as that right from the bat **BUT** you can make one easily using simple `Grid`, `Button`, `StackPanel` controls.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve that, I would advise to start with [some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy workaround is to just use a `TextBlock` instead of specifying the `Header` and place it on top of the `ListView`, but I prefer your current approach as it's simply neater.

But to make it look like what you want, we will need to modify the default `Style` of the `ListView`, which wraps the `Header` and the items inside a `StackPanel`(child of an `ItemsPresenter`). We don't want that, so we first remove the tempate bindings of `Header` and `HeaderTemplate` from the `ItemsPresenter`, and then we replace the root `Border` with a `Grid`, finally we add a `ContentPresenter` as the `Header` and place it above the `ScrollViewer` (the parent of the `ItemsPresenter`).

You can refer to the following `Style` which does everything that I described above.

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle1"
       TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation"
            Value="Once" />
    <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
            Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
            Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode"
            Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode"
            Value="Enabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode"
            Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <AddDeleteThemeTransition />
                <ContentThemeTransition />
                <ReorderThemeTransition />
                <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                <Grid BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Header" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                  BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}"
                                  HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                  IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                  IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                  IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                  TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                  ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                        <ItemsPresenter FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}"
                                        FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}"
                                        Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you just apply it to your `ListView` like this. Oh BTW, make sure you set the `VerticalAlignment` to `Top` too.

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle1}"
          ...>
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works pretty well @Justin, thanks! But is there another control I can use in the future to have the same behaviour? And what about the "Ratings" below the items?

Comment: Nope and please ask a separate question for it.